# Can hepatitis B also infect vaccinated persons?

Tags: pathology

If a person is vaccinated against hepatitis B: Is there any chance that he also gets the infection by physical contact? Is it a congenital disease or not (if the parent is hepatitis positive is the offspring is also affected or not)?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it better understandable, feel free to roll back the edit if it not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but the chance is somewhat low - 10%.

You can check to be sure that the level of surface antibody in your blood is efficient by a simple blood test.

The Hepatitis B vaccine is very effective at preventing Hepatitis B virus infection. After receiving all three doses, Hepatitis B vaccine provides greater than **90% protection** to infants, children, and adults immunized before being exposed to the virus.

In highly endemic areas, Hepatitis B is most commonly spread from mother to child at birth (perinatal transmission), or through horizontal transmission (exposure to infected blood), especially from an infected child to an uninfected child during the first 5 years of life.

Find more about this here:

http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs204/en/

You can find all about Hepatitis B vaccine on the CDC's website:

http://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vpd-vac/hepb/public/index.html